# php_gmp.dll malware

Tags: security

Prevx said this file was infected. What is it and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file appears to be part of a PHP library extension for computing large numbers such as floating point numbers and signed integers (according to this [forum discussion](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread205423.html#)).

Safe bet would be to run an online antivirus scan, such as the ones suggested by DrJekl.

Comment: Then what do I do if it turns out my computer is infected?

Comment: The scanner will probably be able to remove the infection.

Answer (score 1):

This file is used by both safe and unsafe programs. Best action would be to do a complete antivirus scan.  I recommend the online scan from eset.com or housecall.trendmicro.com or both.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to peek in the php.ini file in the extensions area and see if that file is even used (it will have a ; or # in front of it if not used, i forget which). php extensions are enabled/disabled in that file. further, you could rename the file to something else. if you can't rename it, then its in use. if you can rename it, then leave it that way and see if it causes any problems. if not, then delete it at your leisure.

-don